# image script not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code and the problem is the "main" and "left/right" image are not being displayed. I have gone through the entire logic and can't figure out what is wrong.

The code works if I replace `else` with `else if(flag===1 && child[I].id=="left" || child[I].id=="right")`

Expected output:
movement of mouse should change the image, this change is determined by the height of the `<body>` element.

Output getting:
only one image is displayed and does not changes no mater where I move my mouse.

[ also changing event from "mouseover" to "mousemove" does not help ]

so why isn't it working when I remove it, shouldn't at least "main" work??

PS: I'm unable to provide an image, please find another one.

```js
'use strict';
(function() {
    var wlen = screen.availWidth;
    var whet = screen.availHeight;
    var last = {};
    var chk = 3;
    var eye = document.getElementsByClassName("eyes");

    var build = function(ele) {

        if (ele.previousElementSibling !== null) ele.previousElementSibling.style = "none";
        last = ele.style;

        last.display = "block";


    }

    var anite = function() {
        var x = event.screenX;
        var y = event.screenY;
        last.display = "none";
        var child;
        var flag;
        y < whet / 3 ? flag = 2 : (y > 2 * whet / 3) ? flag = 0 : flag = 1;

        x < wlen / 2 ? child = eye[1].childNodes : child = eye[0].childNodes;
        for (let i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
            if (child[i].id) {
                if (child[i].id == "main" && flag === 0) {
                    build(child[i]);

                } else if (child[i].id.search(/a/i) === 0 && flag === 2) {
                    build(child[i]);

                } else {
                    build(child[i]);

                }
            }

        }
    }
    document.addEventListener("mouseover", anite, false);

})()
```

```css
html,body {
   height: 100%;
}

 body {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

 main {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}

 .eyes {
   width:50%;
   float: left;
   height: 300px;
}

 #main {
   background: url('eyes.png') no-repeat 0 0;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 254px;
   display:none;
}

 #left {
   background: url('eyes.png') no-repeat 0 -254px;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 254px;
   display:none;
}

 #aLeft {
   background: url('eyes.png') no-repeat 0 -508px;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 254px;
   display:none;
}

 #right {
   background: url('eyes.png') no-repeat 0 -762px;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 254px;
   display:none;
}

 #aRight {
   background: url('eyes.png') no-repeat 0 -1016px;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 280px;
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Student Details</title>
  </head>

  <body>
      <main>
          <div class="eyes">
              <!-- <img src="eyes.png" alt="eyes"> -->
              <p id="main"></p>
              <p id="right"></p>
              <p id="aRight"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="eyes">
              <p id="main"></p>
              <p id="left"></p>
              <p id="aLeft"></p>
          </div>
      </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you start fixing the reference errors in your code snippet?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: lelio I fail to see any reference error, could you point to exactly which one your referring to??